# Realistic measurement errors on simulated observations

Tags: simulation, error, measurement-error

I have a code that simulates stars in a galaxy, outputting positions and velocities.
I plug this data into another code to do some further analysis.
Normally you'd also put in instrumental errors of these observations of velocities and positions, which are not constant through the data set.
I would like to come up with "realistic" errors for my simulated data to plug into this other code. How would I go about this?

My thinking is to look at real data sets from the same instruments and see whether there is a pattern in errors, then extrapolate, would that be sensible?